# javascript question about sorting array with timestamps

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, jquery-multisortable

I am not that familiar with sorting arrays and objects within Javascript and are wondering about how you would sort out objects after certain conditions.
The end goal is use this sorting in a calendar function.

So as an example let's say we have a situation like the snippet below:

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', '.event', function(){
  var box_date    = $(this).attr('date');
  var param       = [];
  $(`.day[date=${box_date}] .event`).each(function(){
    var box         = $(this);
    var row         = {};
    var time_start  = box.attr('time_start');
    var time_end    = box.attr('time_end');
    var id_event    = box.attr('id_event');
    var time_diff   = timeDiff(time_start, time_end);
    row.time_start  = time_start;
    row.time_end    = time_end;
    row.diff        = time_diff;
    row.id_event    = id_event;
    param.push(row);
  })
  console.log(param);
  param.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.time_start < b.time_start){
            return -1;
        } else if (a.time_start > b.time_start){
            return 1;
        } else if (b.diff - a.diff) return -1;
        return 1;
    });
  console.log(param);
})

function timeDiff(time_start, time_end){
    var today = new Date(),
            month = today.getMonth() + 1,
            day   = today.getDate(),
            year  = today.getFullYear();
      
    month     = month.toString();
    month     = month.padStart(2,'0');
    day       = day.toString();
    day       = day.padStart(2, '0');
    date      = [year, month, day].join('-');
    var date1 = `${date} ${time_start}`;
    var date2 = `${date} ${time_end}`;
    date1     = new Date(date1);
    date2     = new Date(date2);

    var diff_time = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
  // convert the time diff from ms to min
    diff_time = diff_time / (1000 * 60);
    return diff_time;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day" date="2021-02-21">
 <div class="event" id_event="1" date="2021-02-21" time_start="10:00" time_end="10:30">Val1</div>
 <div class="event" id_event="2" date="2021-02-21" time_start="10:00" time_end="11:00">Val2</div>
 <div class="event" id_event="3" date="2021-02-21" time_start="10:00" time_end="12:00">Val3</div>
 <div class="event" id_event="4" date="2021-02-21" time_start="09:30" time_end="12:00">Val4</div>
 <div class="event" id_event="5" date="2021-02-21" time_start="13:00" time_end="15:00">Val5</div>
</div>
```

Let's just not focus on how to get the data into arrays or object but rather the process of sorting the data into the right order / format.

| event id | date | time start | time end | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-21 | 10:00 | 10:30 | 30 |
| 2 | 2021-02-21 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 60 |
| 3 | 2021-02-21 | 10:00 | 12:00 | 120 |
| 4 | 2021-02-21 | 09:30 | 12:00 | 150 |
| 5 | 2021-02-21 | 13:00 | 15:00 | 120 |

When fetching the data they appear as in the order above but since each and every element both can be moved and extended / reduced by the user, I need to set the z-index of the event divs accordingly for styling purposes.

That means that once the positioning of the elements are done and the original data is according to the data above, I need to sort the data according with the following conditions:

1. The earliest start date as first.
2. If 2 elements have the same start date, the one with longer duration has precedence over the other one

By following that logic the above result should end up following the following order

| event id | date | time start | time end | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2021-02-21 | 09:30 | 12:00 | 150 |
| 3 | 2021-02-21 | 10:00 | 12:00 | 120 |
| 2 | 2021-02-21 | 10:00 | 11:00 | 60 |
| 1 | 2021-02-21 | 10:00 | 10:30 | 30 |
| 5 | 2021-02-21 | 13:00 | 15:00 | 120 |

I've updated the snippet with a working example, but if there are better ways of accomplishing the same thing, please let me know.

/C

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Gotcha! I will post my tries after some sleep!

Comment: I've updated my snippet with a working copy of the code but, still would like to know if there are better ways of writing the code. Any feedback on is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sort comparator function must take into account the possibility that two keys (times) are equal.  In that case, it must return 0.

Comment: @Pointy well if it's not greater than or lower than, it is equal and in the comparison that's when you compare the duration. if both duration and start times are equal, I guess I could  consider comparing titles, but... for now that's not really an issue. In my mind your proposal is kind of obsolete in this case but if not, please let me know why.

Comment: If your comparator does not return consistent results when the "diff" values are the same, your sort will produce unpredictable results. There is no guarantee that two elements from the array will be compared in the same order if they are compared more than once.

Comment: Also if the "diff" value is a number, you can just return `b.diff - a.diff` and that will take care of the problem.

Comment: @Pointy noted. I was considering doing as you recommended b.diff - a.diff but got it working without it. Since the consistency is preferred though I will adjust after your recommendation. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing as you would with SQL.

```sql
FROM events
ORDER BY time_start ASC, time_end DESC
```

In JavaScript this can be done in the following manner:

```js
events.sort((a, b) => {
  // time_start ascending
  if (a.time_start < b.time_start) return -1;
  if (a.time_start > b.time_start) return  1;
  // time_end descending
  if (a.time_end < b.time_end) return  1;
  if (a.time_end > b.time_end) return -1;
  // equal
  return 0;
});
```

Note that this is based on character comparison, which works because your times are zero padded and in the 24h notation. This fails for the time `4:20` which should be `04:20`. Without the `0` in front it will be considered *later* than for example `12:42` because `4 (code 0x34) > 1 (code 0x31)` (first characters).

I've also added a more descriptive option, but this does introduce some helper functions.

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', '.event', function(){
  var box_date    = $(this).attr('date');
  var param       = [];
  $(`.day[date=${box_date}] .event`).each(function(){
    var box         = $(this);
    var row         = {};
    var time_start  = box.attr('time_start');
    var time_end    = box.attr('time_end');
    var id_event    = box.attr('id_event');
    row.time_start  = time_start;
    row.time_end    = time_end;
    row.id_event    = id_event;
    param.push(row);
  })
  console.log(param);
  param.sort((a, b) => {
    // time_start ascending
    if (a.time_start < b.time_start) return -1;
    if (a.time_start > b.time_start) return  1;
    // time_end descending
    if (a.time_end < b.time_end) return  1;
    if (a.time_end > b.time_end) return -1;
    // equal
    return 0;
  });
  console.log(param);
  // or if you don't mind introducing some helpers
  param.sort(asc(event => event.time_start).chain(desc(event => event.time_end)));
  console.log(param);
})

// helpers
function asc(mapFn) {
  return attachComparatorMethods(function (a, b) {
    a = mapFn(a);
    b = mapFn(b);
    return -(a < b) || +(a > b);
  });
}

function desc(mapFn) {
  const comparator = asc(mapFn);
  return attachComparatorMethods(function (a, b) {
    return comparator(b, a);
  });
}

function attachComparatorMethods(comparator) {
  return Object.assign(comparator, {
    chain(comparator) {
      return attachComparatorMethods((a, b) => this(a, b) || comparator(a, b));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="day" date="2021-02-21">
  <div class="event" id_event="1" date="2021-02-21" time_start="10:00" time_end="10:30">Val1</div>
  <div class="event" id_event="2" date="2021-02-21" time_start="10:00" time_end="11:00">Val2</div>
  <div class="event" id_event="3" date="2021-02-21" time_start="10:00" time_end="12:00">Val3</div>
  <div class="event" id_event="4" date="2021-02-21" time_start="09:30" time_end="12:00">Val4</div>
  <div class="event" id_event="5" date="2021-02-21" time_start="13:00" time_end="15:00">Val5</div>
</div>
```

If you have issues understanding the `asc` helper, it is probably due to the line:

```
return -(a < b) || +(a > b);
```

Which could also be written as:

```
if (a < b) return -1;
if (a > b) return  1;
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will give this a try later on!